# recompiling a new apk after decompiling and modifying the previous apk

Tags: java, android, decompiling, recompile, apktool

I have de-compiled an apk file using apk-tool (command: "apktool d file.apk") and changed some xml parts.

Also I have the jar file using dex2jar. I opened jar with java de-compiler and selected "save all sources". Then I unzipped it and changed some parts of the code (modified it).

Now how  should I regenerate the new apk file?? I tried copying java sources into the folder from apk-tool and the recompiled them together but it didn't work. What should I do??

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mix technologies that aren't possible to mix. Apktool during rebuild requires files to be either in the pre-assembled `dex` format or various disassembled `.smali` files.

Apktool doesn't have any support to build from java sources. Not to mention, it wouldn't work as Apktool can't rewrite resource IDs which would happen with java sources. You can read the technical explanation [here](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/199).

You need to build your java sources, then use `baksmali` to obtain the `.smali` equivalence and use those in apktool.